# Windows 8 Snap View

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

In the Windows 8 Store App certification requirements it states that your app must support a snapped view. My question is that Can we provide the static splash screen page as our snap view throughout the application? Windows accept application with a single page as a snap view?

Comment: At the present I got 0 experience in writing for windows 8 store app but, if you consider that windows 8 is a smartphone OS and not really a desktop OS.. static splash screen page sounds like something that would miss the concept of a snapped view.

Comment: @G.Y - Windows 8 is NOT (yet) a smartphone OS.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd :) Let me quote someone: "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then what is it?" -BB Netanyahu, PM of Israel, UN meeting regarding Iran Nuclear Reactor.

Comment: @G.Y: You are wrong. "The minimum resolution in which Windows Store apps will run is 1024x768. The minimum resolution required to support all the features of Windows 8 (including multitasking with snap) is 1366x768. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh780612) " That does not sound very smartphony, and it isn't. Win8 is a tablet and desktop OS.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus I can live with calling it tablet OS. but desktop OS... come on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapped View has its purpose ofcourse but in many situations it is hard to deal with it so you could represent data in the best way possible.

They will accept, however, a static screen as the Snapped View. They had with an app of mine and it passed their certification.

Furthermore, if you think about it, even the "Store" app has a static image as a snapped page.

Comment: Thanks Vasile for your quick response to my specific requirement. I am having one more question, if i am targeting my application for Win 8.1 then same functionality will it be accept as a windows app store standards?

Comment: I don't know for sure what requirements they will have for 8.1. But in any case think of it like this : 8.1, has a wider snapped mode for the purpose of better showing the data. I guess, a static image will still be accepted, but ignoring the snapped view like this with a simple static image, might make the users less satisfied of your app.

Comment: Now, I read your comment better : If the functionality doesn't change (you said "same functionality"), I'd say leave it to 8 and don't target it to 8.1.

Comment: No snapped view in windows 8.1 anymore. What you get is screens splits between apps in ratios of 70/30, 60/40 or 50/50. And I bet microsoft would expect all apps to work in those split modes. So in the essence your app's UI should be flexible enough to work in different sizes and aspect rations.

Answer (score 0):

As things stand today, Snapped view is mandatory. Its however at times difficult to implement snapped view. In such situations, the developer can chose to hide everything except something that informs the user to not use snapped view.

I tend to use a simple button that states the same and onclick the app try TryUnsnap to expand out.

Beyond this: 8.1 makes snap support optional

Comment: not to be pedantic, but while you can opt into the snapped state size for 8.1 - TryUnsnap never succeeds, so looking forward you may want to forego that approach even in 8 and rely on the user manually dragging the splitter to resize.

Comment: Very true.. Try unsnap isn't supported in 8.1 and apps will have to be reworked / recompiled for 8.1